# ngx-translate to translate Angular app without refresh the page to fetch all data from BE

Tags: angular-translate

How to use ngx-translate to translate Angular app without refresh the page to fetch all data from BE again with the new language header?

Answer (score 0):

Use either the TranslatePipe or the TranslateDirective to get your translation values.

Like: `<div [translate]="'HELLO'" [translateParams]="{value: 'world'}"></div>`

or: `<p>{{ 'ROLES.' + role | uppercase | translate }}</p>`

If you get your translations in the component.ts and you do not want to refresh, you have to use the observables to get the changes:

```
translate.get('HELLO', {value: 'world'}).subscribe((res: string) => {
    console.log(res);
    //=> 'hello world'
});
```

Comment: Yes, you are right but this is not the problem. I want to have centered solution to fetch new data from BE with the new selected language. In other words do a silent refresh for the current rendered components.